# Update UI after ajax response for iron-form in Polymer

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a problem where an ajax request is not updating the UI. I need to manually refresh the page.

Basically it's a like button. When pressed, it should increase the number of likes. The HTTP request and response are working fine. But the value `{{commentaire.likes}}`does not get updated immediately.

```
<template>
    <form is="iron-form" id="likeForm" method="post" action="/like/{{commentaire.heure}}" on-click="submitLike" on-iron-form-response="augmenterLikes">
        <paper-button raised>{{commentaire.likes}} J'aime</paper-button>        
    </form>

</template>

<script>


    Polymer({

        is: 'my-comment',
        properties: {
            commentaire : {
                type: Object,
                value: {},                  
            },
        }, 

        augmenterLikes: function(e) {
            this.commentaire.likes = e.detail.response;
        },



    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to update deep properties you must use the `set` method, for example in your case:

```
this.set('commentaire.likes', e.detail.response);
```

I've made an example using a random number generator in here: https://jsfiddle.net/fLbf6uag/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder where from the docs or a tutorial you got that from.

Comment: Hi, you can check it here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#set-path the solution can be done also using your `this.commentaire.likes = e.detail.response` + `this.notify('commentaire.likes ', this.commentaire.likes)`, but `set` is a cleaner solution.